# cannot boot Debian Jessie installed via debootstrap

Tags: debian, debootstrap

I've just installed a Debian Jessie via debootsrap for testing/learning purpouse, this is its entry in the GRUB menu:

```
menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux (jessie/sid) (on /dev/mapper/nostromo-DEBIAN)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
   insmod lvm
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ext2
   set root='(nostromo-DEBIAN)'
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f8ae3cc5-384a-484e-a701-76754242baf3
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.14-2-rt-amd64 root=/dev/dm-2
   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.14-2-rt-amd64
}
```

As you can see I use lvm2. Unfortunately, the boot process fails because it cannot find the /dev/dm-2 partition. In facts running `ls /dev/` from busybox console the dm-* devices are all missing, but if I launch another system and I access the new installation via chroot, dm-* devices are present. How can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need a module for the raid stuff? I have both `insmod raid` and `insmod mdraid1x` in my grub config. In that order.

Comment: I don't think so, my running host distro does not use any, although it runs on a logical volume too.